# Возможно ли управление ресурсами при выполнении тяжелых запросов

Tags: postgresql

Скажем есть запрос, который потребляет оперативной памяти больше чем есть. Понятное дело что он часть своего выполнения работы перенесет в файл подкачки. Так же он потребляет процессорное время.

Можно ли как то установить ограничения на потребляемые ресурсы и не потерять работоспособность пожертвовав только временем выполнения.

Используемая СУБД postgres ОС windows.

Comment: Странно, обычно СУБД сама контролирует этот момент и выбирает план выполнения из данных ей в настройках ресурсов и уходит не в файл подкачки, а в использование временных таблиц. Неужели postgresql работает не так ...

Comment: @Mike смотри как получилось. я написал скрипт на процедурном языке и опробовал его на рабочей станции. он честно отработал на 100 записях.

Отдал его на проверку, а там машина послабей моей и записей на 100 гигов и мне сказали что он завис. Вот меня и берут теперь сомнения. Я подумал может в конфиге можно прописать другие параметры чтоб не предъявляли что мол я кривой.

Comment: Ну на 100 гигах конечно он будет выполнятся очень долго, если например ему действительно надо перебрать все эти записи. И да, обычно приложение выполняющее запрос висит пока он не выполнится. От того что вы сможете как то управлять ресурсами скорость работы точно не вырастет. А если виснет не скрипт, а машина целиком - то это уже вопрос к тем кто ставил там postges, не выделил ли он глобально всему постгресу памяти больше, чем ее доступно (в postgresql.conf)

Comment: @Mike на сервере свой скрипт запустил я. и не видил финала. просто я подозреваю что он отработал. а потом базу восстановили. Мне просто доказать возможно придется что мой скрипт 100% рабочий, вот я и подумал покажу на 100 записях а если потребуется то я сервер настрою что бы он не повешал машину и пусть он до посинения работает пока не сделает всю работу до конца.

Comment: Т.е. от вашего скрипта наглухо виснет машина ? Это что то сверхестественное. Может быть например если сбой по диску пройдет на файлах БД. но что бы все ресурсы так жестко отнять ... А ваше приложение просто отдает запрос в БД и все, данные из запроса оно в свои массивы не читает ? Это я к тому, что может памяти не хватает не БД, а приложению. А что до настроек postgresql, то запрос к гуглу "postgresql настройка выделения памяти" дает много интересного. И если это единый запрос что то в БД меняющий, то если он до итогового commit после запроса не дойдет то в БД ничего не изменится ...

Comment: @Mike если бы я видел этот висяк собственными глазами то вопросов было бы меньше. Просто хотелось бы убедится в том что я не дурак и в случае чего доказать это.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59100/discussion-between-perfect-and-mike).

Comment: Postgresql и windows - несовместимые вещи... Досели я не могу четко озвучить в чем именно проблема. Однако имел так же беду, при INSERT в 10000 записей винда выполняла вставку 30 - 45 - 50 минут, как повезет. В то же время та же бд, той же структуры только на Linux делала вставку за 0,5-2 секунд... в зависимости от нагрузки на сервер (оба сервера по железу идентичны). Полагаю трабла в том что винда, не умеет форкать процессы так же как linux